# HTML5 - Obstruir acesso direto ao áudio

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de proteger arquivos de áudio em um diretório público do apache.
Não pretendo necessariamente fazer o download do arquivo (vi várias dicas sobre) e sim reproduzi-lo no navegador somente para usuários que tem sessão ativa.
Já alterei o `.htaccess` para não listar os arquivos do diretório, mas eles ainda são acessados diretamente pela URL sem precisar está logado.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="/audios/audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

A única gambiarra que imaginei foi colocar os arquivos no diretório `/home/user/audios`, por exemplo, e quando o usuário quiser escutar, copiar o áudio para a pasta pública e reproduzi-lo. Seria necessário também uma rotina para apagar os arquivos periodicamente.

Gostaria de poder ter uma segunda opinião.

Grato desde já.

PS. Estou utilizando PHP.

Answer (score 0):

No seu arquivo `.htaccess` acrescente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+.)?seusite.com/audios [NC]RewriteRule .*.(wav|mp3)$ http://www.seusite.com/erro.php [L]
```